# Postfix cant send mails to own domain

Tags: email, ubuntu, postfix-mta

I am currently using postfix as a mail application on my server (ubuntu 18.04.5, Apache 2.4.29). The problem is now that I can send: adress.mydomain.com -> adress.otherdomain.com but not mails: adress.mydomain.com -> adress.mydomain.com (which is important for my application). [I read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621203/emails-with-same-domain-does-not-go-out-from-postfix) that you should leave mydestination empty in main.cf. However, it doesn't work that way either. 
Here is my main.cf file:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/README_FILES

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = [The domain from my plesk server]
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination =
relayhost =
mynetworks =
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter =
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/sbin
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
command_directory = /usr/sbin
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/samples
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
mail_owner = postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
html_directory = no
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
shlib_directory = no
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
```